# log4net not logging properly when rolling to a new date

Tags: log4net, rollingfileappender

Log4Net worked fine for a few months and then started giving problems when rolling out a new file for the next day.

Problem:
Whenever I check in the daytime or until 23:59 everything is logged but as soon as it rolls over, the rolled file will have the data of 00:00 - 06:00 hrs of the next day. All the logs of the previous day are lost.

So for the rolledfile Service.log20100702 will contain the data 00:00 - 06:00 hrs for 03/07/2010 date and nothing else.

The problem is mainly on the Production boxes, it's working fine on my local box.

My rolling file appender looks like

```xml
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\TTLLogs\Refunds\Ttl.Refunds.Web.UI.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <header value="[Header]&#xA;"/>
        <footer value="[Footer]&#xA;"/>
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger ${COMPUTERNAME} %property{UserHostAddress} [%property{SessionID}] - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appender>
```

Comment: Have you hit the maximumFileSize limit perhaps?
Is there an automated process or similar that runs around 06:00 hours that could be locking the system up? I.e. Are the last log entries similar each day or completely random.

Comment: its not 06:00 hrs everyday, its random. In the past the size till 457 MBs. So its reaching the limit but its not rolling after maximumFileSize and the maxSizeRollBackups is 100 so it shouldnt be a problem. Any idea why thts happening?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try:

- Adding <[staticLogFileName value="true" /](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.StaticLogFileName.html)>. This prevents file renaming when the appender rolls the date.
- Change the lockingModel to [FileAppender.ExclusiveLock](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.LockingModel.html) to prevent another process from locking the log file. I.e. maybe a virus scanner of similar is locking the log file.
- Removing [maximumFileSize](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.MaximumFileSize.html) as it isn't applicable when the [rollingStyle](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingStyle.html) is Date.
- Removing [maxSizeRollBackups](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.MaxSizeRollBackups.html) as you can manually delete the extra log files until the logging is working as expected again.